# android - log out from Google integration in android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I am signing out from google integration by following:

```
 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                               new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResult(Status status) {
                                       AndyConstants.loginorout = false;
                                       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);
                                   }
                               });
```

now the problem is that in `onResult()` I am starting activity named HomeAvtivity but after signing out i am redirected to an activity(RegisterActivity) where google login button is present instead of HomeActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution that I was not connecting ***GoogleApiClient*** in `onResume()` and thus it was crashing because ***GoogleApiClient*** was null. So just add following to your code and above function will log out user from google integration successfully.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```